# Why does the Hidden/Fastblur shader no longer work on iOS for Unity 2018?

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, shader, hlsl

Context:
If you google for Hidden/Fatblur, you'll find multiple urls where this shader is available, i won't post any link here because i don't know where the original is located.
It's basically a shader for blurring that should be optimized for mobile devices.

Problem:
If you used this shader in the past and just updated your Unity version to 2018+, the shader stops working.

What i tried:
I messed up the shader in the Editor... hear the god news, was able to get the same symptoms. So I know the issue is in the way this shader is compiled on my iOS device. No shader errors though during the unity ->x Code project compilation.

Question:
How do I fix the shader such that it works again?

Here is the shader code that is not working:

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'


Shader "Hidden/FastBlur" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Bloom ("Bloom (RGB)", 2D) = "black" {}
}

CGINCLUDE

    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    sampler2D _Bloom;

    uniform half4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
    half4 _MainTex_ST;

    half4 _Bloom_ST;

    uniform half4 _Parameter;

    struct v2f_tap
    {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        half2 uv20 : TEXCOORD0;
        half2 uv21 : TEXCOORD1;
        half2 uv22 : TEXCOORD2;
        half2 uv23 : TEXCOORD3;
    };          

    v2f_tap vert4Tap ( appdata_img v )
    {
        v2f_tap o;

        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);
        o.uv20 = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord + _MainTex_TexelSize.xy, _MainTex_ST);
        o.uv21 = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord + _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(-0.5h,-0.5h), _MainTex_ST);
        o.uv22 = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord + _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(0.5h,-0.5h), _MainTex_ST);
        o.uv23 = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord + _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(-0.5h,0.5h), _MainTex_ST);

        return o; 
    }                   

    fixed4 fragDownsample ( v2f_tap i ) : SV_Target
    {               
        fixed4 color = tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv20);
        color += tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv21);
        color += tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv22);
        color += tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv23);
        return color / 4;
    }

    // weight curves

    static const half curve[7] = { 0.0205, 0.0855, 0.232, 0.324, 0.232, 0.0855, 0.0205 };  // gauss'ish blur weights

    static const half4 curve4[7] = { half4(0.0205,0.0205,0.0205,0), half4(0.0855,0.0855,0.0855,0), half4(0.232,0.232,0.232,0),
        half4(0.324,0.324,0.324,1), half4(0.232,0.232,0.232,0), half4(0.0855,0.0855,0.0855,0), half4(0.0205,0.0205,0.0205,0) };

    struct v2f_withBlurCoords8 
    {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        half4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        half2 offs : TEXCOORD1;
    };  

    struct v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX 
    {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        half4 offs[3] : TEXCOORD1;
    };

    v2f_withBlurCoords8 vertBlurHorizontal (appdata_img v)
    {
        v2f_withBlurCoords8 o;
        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);

        o.uv = half4(v.texcoord.xy,1,1);
        o.offs = _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(1.0, 0.0) * _Parameter.x;

        return o; 
    }

    v2f_withBlurCoords8 vertBlurVertical (appdata_img v)
    {
        v2f_withBlurCoords8 o;
        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);

        o.uv = half4(v.texcoord.xy,1,1);
        o.offs = _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(0.0, 1.0) * _Parameter.x;

        return o; 
    }   

    half4 fragBlur8 ( v2f_withBlurCoords8 i ) : SV_Target
    {
        half2 uv = i.uv.xy; 
        half2 netFilterWidth = i.offs;  
        half2 coords = uv - netFilterWidth * 3.0;  

        half4 color = 0;
        for( int l = 0; l < 7; l++ )  
        {   
            half4 tap = tex2D(_MainTex, UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(coords, _MainTex_ST));
            color += tap * curve4[l];
            coords += netFilterWidth;
        }
        return color;
    }


    v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX vertBlurHorizontalSGX (appdata_img v)
    {
        v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX o;
        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);

        o.uv = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xy, _MainTex_ST);

        half offsetMagnitude = _MainTex_TexelSize.x * _Parameter.x;
        o.offs[0] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(-3.0h, 0.0h, 3.0h, 0.0h), _MainTex_ST);
        o.offs[1] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(-2.0h, 0.0h, 2.0h, 0.0h), _MainTex_ST);
        o.offs[2] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(-1.0h, 0.0h, 1.0h, 0.0h), _MainTex_ST);

        return o; 
    }

    v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX vertBlurVerticalSGX (appdata_img v)
    {
        v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX o;
        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);

        o.uv = half4(UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xy, _MainTex_ST),1,1);

        half offsetMagnitude = _MainTex_TexelSize.y * _Parameter.x;
        o.offs[0] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(0.0h, -3.0h, 0.0h, 3.0h), _MainTex_ST);
        o.offs[1] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(0.0h, -2.0h, 0.0h, 2.0h), _MainTex_ST);
        o.offs[2] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(0.0h, -1.0h, 0.0h, 1.0h), _MainTex_ST);

        return o; 
    }

    half4 fragBlurSGX ( v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX i ) : SV_Target
    {
        half2 uv = i.uv.xy;

        half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * curve4[3];

        for( int l = 0; l < 3; l++ )  
        {   
            half4 tapA = tex2D(_MainTex, i.offs[l].xy);
            half4 tapB = tex2D(_MainTex, i.offs[l].zw); 
            color += (tapA + tapB) * curve4[l];
        }

        return color;

    }   

ENDCG

SubShader {
  ZTest Off Cull Off ZWrite Off Blend Off

// 0
Pass { 

    CGPROGRAM

    #pragma vertex vert4Tap
    #pragma fragment fragDownsample

    ENDCG

    }

// 1
Pass {
    ZTest Always
    Cull Off

    CGPROGRAM 

    #pragma vertex vertBlurVertical
    #pragma fragment fragBlur8

    ENDCG 
    }   

// 2
Pass {      
    ZTest Always
    Cull Off

    CGPROGRAM

    #pragma vertex vertBlurHorizontal
    #pragma fragment fragBlur8

    ENDCG
    }   

// alternate blur
// 3
Pass {
    ZTest Always
    Cull Off

    CGPROGRAM 

    #pragma vertex vertBlurVerticalSGX
    #pragma fragment fragBlurSGX

    ENDCG
    }   

// 4
Pass {      
    ZTest Always
    Cull Off

    CGPROGRAM

    #pragma vertex vertBlurHorizontalSGX
    #pragma fragment fragBlurSGX

    ENDCG
    }   
}   

FallBack Off
}
```

Comment: Without posting any code your question and also your answer are useless.

Comment: i explained how you get the code. it's a commonly used shader.
i explained how to change the code, where i explained what the reason for it not working is, such that people don't just copy paste the replaced code for the particular shader problem, but if they find this stack overflow question becaue of some other shader that stopped working in the new unity3d version, they might be able to fix it using the same fix pattern.

So thanks for the thumbs down but it's actually a really good question and answer

Comment: As soon as you add the relevant code for reproducing and solving the issue I will retrieve the downvotes .. until than both remain useless and not within the community rules as [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: there you go. I really just shared this because it frustrated me, and i found no answer to it when researching the web. After a while I asked a friend of mine who was like: did you try unrolling for loops and replacing if-else statements with some mathematical representation? because that is often the wtf reason behind shaders bugging for no reason.
I tried the unrolling first, since it's the easiest... and behold: shader compilers are sh*ty.
Really just having the good intention to relieve others from this frustration by giving them the answer sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to unroll the for loops:
There are 2 loops (one of size `3`, and one of size `7`)
Just unroll them manually, replacing `[l]` with `[0]` etc.

The shader now gets properly compiled and you get the desired results again on your iOS device!

Here is the modified shader code such that it works:

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'


Shader "Hidden/FastBlur" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Bloom ("Bloom (RGB)", 2D) = "black" {}
    }

    CGINCLUDE

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _Bloom;

        uniform half4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
        half4 _MainTex_ST;

        half4 _Bloom_ST;

        uniform half4 _Parameter;

        struct v2f_tap
        {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            half2 uv20 : TEXCOORD0;
            half2 uv21 : TEXCOORD1;
            half2 uv22 : TEXCOORD2;
            half2 uv23 : TEXCOORD3;
        };          

        v2f_tap vert4Tap ( appdata_img v )
        {
            v2f_tap o;

            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);
            o.uv20 = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord + _MainTex_TexelSize.xy, _MainTex_ST);
            o.uv21 = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord + _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(-0.5h,-0.5h), _MainTex_ST);
            o.uv22 = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord + _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(0.5h,-0.5h), _MainTex_ST);
            o.uv23 = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord + _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(-0.5h,0.5h), _MainTex_ST);

            return o; 
        }                   

        fixed4 fragDownsample ( v2f_tap i ) : SV_Target
        {               
            fixed4 color = tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv20);
            color += tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv21);
            color += tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv22);
            color += tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv23);
            return color / 4;
        }

        // weight curves

        static const half curve[7] = { 0.0205, 0.0855, 0.232, 0.324, 0.232, 0.0855, 0.0205 };  // gauss'ish blur weights

        static const half4 curve4[7] = { half4(0.0205,0.0205,0.0205,0), half4(0.0855,0.0855,0.0855,0), half4(0.232,0.232,0.232,0),
            half4(0.324,0.324,0.324,1), half4(0.232,0.232,0.232,0), half4(0.0855,0.0855,0.0855,0), half4(0.0205,0.0205,0.0205,0) };

        struct v2f_withBlurCoords8 
        {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            half4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            half2 offs : TEXCOORD1;
        };  

        struct v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX 
        {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            half4 offs[3] : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        v2f_withBlurCoords8 vertBlurHorizontal (appdata_img v)
        {
            v2f_withBlurCoords8 o;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);

            o.uv = half4(v.texcoord.xy,1,1);
            o.offs = _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(1.0, 0.0) * _Parameter.x;

            return o; 
        }

        v2f_withBlurCoords8 vertBlurVertical (appdata_img v)
        {
            v2f_withBlurCoords8 o;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);

            o.uv = half4(v.texcoord.xy,1,1);
            o.offs = _MainTex_TexelSize.xy * half2(0.0, 1.0) * _Parameter.x;

            return o; 
        }   

        half4 fragBlur8 ( v2f_withBlurCoords8 i ) : SV_Target
        {
            half2 uv = i.uv.xy; 
            half2 netFilterWidth = i.offs;  
            half2 coords = uv - netFilterWidth * 3.0;  

            half4 color = 0;

            //for( int l = 0; l < 7; l++ )
            half4 tap = tex2D(_MainTex, UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(coords, _MainTex_ST));
            color += tap * curve4[0];
            coords += netFilterWidth;

            tap = tex2D(_MainTex, UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(coords, _MainTex_ST));
            color += tap * curve4[1];
            coords += netFilterWidth;

            tap = tex2D(_MainTex, UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(coords, _MainTex_ST));
            color += tap * curve4[2];
            coords += netFilterWidth;

            tap = tex2D(_MainTex, UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(coords, _MainTex_ST));
            color += tap * curve4[3];
            coords += netFilterWidth;

            tap = tex2D(_MainTex, UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(coords, _MainTex_ST));
            color += tap * curve4[4];
            coords += netFilterWidth;

            tap = tex2D(_MainTex, UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(coords, _MainTex_ST));
            color += tap * curve4[5];
            coords += netFilterWidth;

            tap = tex2D(_MainTex, UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(coords, _MainTex_ST));
            color += tap * curve4[6];
            coords += netFilterWidth;

            return color;
        }


        v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX vertBlurHorizontalSGX (appdata_img v)
        {
            v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX o;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);

            o.uv = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xy, _MainTex_ST);

            half offsetMagnitude = _MainTex_TexelSize.x * _Parameter.x;
            o.offs[0] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(-3.0h, 0.0h, 3.0h, 0.0h), _MainTex_ST);
            o.offs[1] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(-2.0h, 0.0h, 2.0h, 0.0h), _MainTex_ST);
            o.offs[2] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(-1.0h, 0.0h, 1.0h, 0.0h), _MainTex_ST);

            return o; 
        }

        v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX vertBlurVerticalSGX (appdata_img v)
        {
            v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX o;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);

            o.uv = half4(UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xy, _MainTex_ST),1,1);

            half offsetMagnitude = _MainTex_TexelSize.y * _Parameter.x;
            o.offs[0] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(0.0h, -3.0h, 0.0h, 3.0h), _MainTex_ST);
            o.offs[1] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(0.0h, -2.0h, 0.0h, 2.0h), _MainTex_ST);
            o.offs[2] = UnityStereoScreenSpaceUVAdjust(v.texcoord.xyxy + offsetMagnitude * half4(0.0h, -1.0h, 0.0h, 1.0h), _MainTex_ST);

            return o; 
        }

        half4 fragBlurSGX ( v2f_withBlurCoordsSGX i ) : SV_Target
        {
            half2 uv = i.uv.xy;

            half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * curve4[3];

            //for( int l = 0; l < 3; l++ )
            half4 tapA = tex2D(_MainTex, i.offs[0].xy);
            half4 tapB = tex2D(_MainTex, i.offs[0].zw); 
            color += (tapA + tapB) * curve4[0];

            tapA = tex2D(_MainTex, i.offs[1].xy);
            tapB = tex2D(_MainTex, i.offs[1].zw); 
            color += (tapA + tapB) * curve4[1];

            tapA = tex2D(_MainTex, i.offs[2].xy);
            tapB = tex2D(_MainTex, i.offs[2].zw); 
            color += (tapA + tapB) * curve4[2];

            return color;

        }   

    ENDCG

    SubShader 
    {
        ZTest Off Cull Off ZWrite Off Blend Off

        // 0
        Pass 
        { 

            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert4Tap
            #pragma fragment fragDownsample

            ENDCG

            }

        // 1
        Pass 
        {
            ZTest Always
            Cull Off

            CGPROGRAM 

            #pragma vertex vertBlurVertical
            #pragma fragment fragBlur8

            ENDCG 
            }   

        // 2
        Pass 
        {      
            ZTest Always
            Cull Off

            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vertBlurHorizontal
            #pragma fragment fragBlur8

            ENDCG
            }   

        // alternate blur
        // 3
        Pass 
        {
            ZTest Always
            Cull Off

            CGPROGRAM 

            #pragma vertex vertBlurVerticalSGX
            #pragma fragment fragBlurSGX

            ENDCG
            }   

        // 4
        Pass 
        {      
            ZTest Always
            Cull Off

            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vertBlurHorizontalSGX
            #pragma fragment fragBlurSGX

            ENDCG
        } 
    }   

    FallBack Off
}
```